# Error: The `revalidate` property is not yet available for general use

Tags: next.js

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.3",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-request": "3.0.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.57",
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "next-seo": "^4.7.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.2.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-static-google-map": "^0.6.2",
    "remark": "^12.0.1",
    "remark-html": "^12.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.7.6",
    "use-position": "^0.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I am trying to use revaildate: 1 in getStaticProps but I am getting error saying

```
Error: The `revalidate` property is not yet available for general use.
To try the experimental implementation, please use `unstable_revalidate` instead.
```

As I can see in package.json file my nextjs version is 9.3.5
Can anyone help me what I should do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "unstable_revalidate" instead of "revalidate", because in nextjs version <9.5, "revalidate" keyword is not yet generalised.